# Hide or remove all breadcrumbs from frontend

Tags: magento2, php, magento-2.1.3

I want to remove all breadcrumbs from frontend.
Is there any short or quick way to remove it.
I tried to remove from back-end:

> web > default page > breadcrumbs to NO

But it is still showing on some pages.

Should I manually add xml to remove from each page/layout?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove it from default.xml file of your theme:

> ```
>     <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
> ```

Path to file: `root/app/design/frontend/VENDOR/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Comment: I override breadcrumbs.phtml in my theme and commented out the code and disappear but I am considering your answer.Thank you.